# A question in Stein's 'Complex Analysis'

Tags: complex-analysis

In page 12 there is a proposition says that if $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, then if we write $F(x, y)=f(z)$, then $F$ is differentiable in the sense of real variables.

In the proof below there is a sentence which makes me a little confused:

To prove that $F$ is differentiable it suffices to observe that if $H=(h_1, h_2)$ and $h=h_1+ih_2$, then the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply 
\begin{equation*}
J_F(x_0, y_0)(H) = \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)(h_1+ih_2), 
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
J= J_F(x, y) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \partial u/\partial x & \partial u/\partial y \\ \partial v/\partial x & \partial v/\partial y \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
Why ???

Comment: it is obvious that $f(x+iy)$ is real differentiable (since it is complex differentiable with respect to $x$ and $y$..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$J_F(H)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial _xu&\partial _yu\\\partial _xv&\partial _yv\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_1\\h_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\partial _x u h_1+\partial _y u h_2\\\partial _x v h_1+\partial _y h_2\end{pmatrix}=\partial _x u h_1+\partial _yu h_2+i(\partial _x v h_1+\partial _yv h_2).$$

Using Cauchy Riemann will allowed you to conclude.

Comment: U r right. Oh god I'm so stupid.